# How to load Chatter with Javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript, chatter, performance

### Question

How can I load chatter (`chatter:feedWithFollowers`) dynamically (using javascript) in the browser?

### Motivation

I'm working on a Visualforce page that should load as fast as possible and the user should be able to open chatter feed when they click on a link.

The page controller and Vf components should be optimized in order to perform fast enough.

However, when I check network traffic in the browser I can see that Salesforce is including  **TONS** of static resources (js, img and css libraries) in order to include chatter and this is taking its toll on the page loading performance.

### So far

I've tried to load it by doing something like this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="toogleChatter();" >Chatter</a>
<apex:actionFunction name="toogleChatter" action="{!toogleChatter}" rerender="chatter" />
<apex:outputPanel id="chatter" >
    <chatter:feedWithFollowers entityId="{!obj.id}" showHeader="true" rendered="{!chatterOn}"/>  
</apex:outputPanel>
```

When chatter loads it has some initialization issue and is not starting well:

[image]

I've noticed that this js error is being throw in the chatterDefer.js

[image: chatterDefer.js Error]

**has someone loaded the chatter component on demand ?**

Comment: Have you looked at ngForce - https://github.com/noeticpenguin/ngForce the library built by Kevin Poorman. It does away with the heavy duty stuff and lets you call the Chatter API without burning API calls or resources.

Comment: Cool library, but I don't want to create the entire chatter functionality in JS, I think that it doesn't allow me to load the standard chatter feed, does it ?

Comment: if you figured anything out, would love to hear it.  running into this same issue myself.